# Incrementar opacidade de um elemento

Tags: javascript

O meu fadeOut está ok, mas o fadeIn nao está a funcionar...

```
function fadeIn(elem, speed)
    {

    if(!elem.style.opacity)
    {
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    InInterval(function(){

 elem.style.opacity += 0.03;

    }, speed /100);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o valor da opacidade é interpretada como uma string (texto), e não como um número. Podes fazer [assim](https://jsfiddle.net/ru4t7vo0/8/):

```js
function fadeIn(elem, speed) {
   if(!elem.style.opacity) {
      elem.style.opacity = 0;
   }
   timer = setInterval(function(){
      if(parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) >= 1) clearInterval(timer);
      elem.style.opacity = parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) + 0.03;
   }, speed / 100);
}

ele = document.getElementById('hey');
fadeIn(ele, 5000);
```

```css
#hey {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hey">

</div>
```

Comment: já funciona, obrigado :)